# How to obtain text from list of elements in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

Consider the following HTML code.

```
<div id="tree" style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;" class="treeview">
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="0" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;">
   <span class="icon glyphicon"></span>
   <span class="icon node-icon glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked">
   </span>
   Apples
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="1" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;">
   <span class="icon glyphicon"></span>
   <span class="icon node-icon glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked">
   </span>
   Bananas
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="2" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;">
   <span class="icon glyphicon"></span>
   <span class="icon node-icon glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked">
   </span>
   Mangoes
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="3" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;">
   <span class="icon glyphicon"></span>
   <span class="icon node-icon glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked">
   </span>
   Grapes
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to obtain the text "Apples", "Bananas", "Mangoes", and "Grapes" using

```
i = 1
m = 2
while i < m:
    css_id = ".list-group-item:nth-child(" + str(i) + ") > .node-icon"
    try:
        fruit_text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_id).text
        print(fruit_text)
        i += 1
        m += 1
    except:
        i += 1
```

but resulting no strings were printed.

Any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you :

```
fruits_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.list-group-item.node-tree')

for fruit in fruits_list:
   print(fruit.text)
```

Just make sure that `.list-group-item.node-tree` this **css selector** should indicates fruits on the web page.